# Is there any way to extend blog plugin to import xml file

Tags: laravel-5.1, octobercms

Just been looking at October cms and I would like to extend the import function to include xml files is this possible in October I have looked on the October forum but unable to find any info on this, I like the way the blog section imports csv file and would like to do something similar but with xml.
I noted that the ImportExportController uses League\Csv\Reader namespace is there something similar for XML

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/klyp-wpimporter) which is supposed to provide importing functionality for Wordpress blog posts (exported from WordPress in xml format) in both [Rainlab.Blog](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-blog) and [RadiantWeb.Problog](https://octobercms.com/plugin/radiantweb-problog) plugins.
From looking at the review comments it might be that there are still some issues with this plugin. But you could try and see how it works and also look through the code to understand its inner machinery.

Comment: Thank you trollkotze I've been looking at creating my own plugin using Guzzle I'll post my results when I completed it thanks again for you time